# Trying to connect sql database which is on host

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite, host

I'm having trouble with trying to connect sql database which is staying in a host machine. I know host machine's ip,password etc etc I can use this host maching as my computer. So here's my problem starting. Normally my database stands at my C:/ folder like "x.sqlite" I did this database with mozilla plugin which named SQLite Manager. Here's my code for connecting to database.

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\x.sqlite");
```

But i need to connect first host machine and show the sqlite file as that code which i gave before that. If you need something, just leave a comment or if you have any answers , feel fre e to share with me please , thanks ^^

Comment: [This link](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteNetwork) may prove useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is not designed for use over a network.  If the remote database is available as a network share or NFS mount you *might* be able to use it, but that is likely to cause data corruption if the connection goes down or has temporary glitches.

Comment: Hmm i got that. So what should i use instead of SQLite ?

Comment: MySQL or PostgreSQL would be logical choices